# How to check if event was fired once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have code in jQuery like this:

```
$("#something").click(function() {  
};
```

and inside function I'd like to check if `#something` was clicked only once at a short time and if twice and more, then act like once.

I tried this code:

```
if(!event.detail || event.detail == 1) { do_something; }
```

and it works in most browsers except Firefox. I know why, but didn't find any solution for this. I tried `preventDefault` on `dblclick` event, but it doesn't work in Chrome...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to fire the event only once. There's a jQuery method `.one()` for that

Comment: I don't want to fire it only once, but once at a short time. If triggered event is completed, then I can trigger it again, but not until it's finished. So, basically, I want to ignore triggering the same event if it's being processed, but after it's done, I want to be able to trigger it again.

Comment: You can disable to button which triggers the event until the processing is finished.

Comment: Ok, but how to check if processing is finished?

Comment: Can you show the code inside `click` function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event.timeStamp` to determine the time between two events.

```
$("#something").click(function( event ) {  
    this.lastClick = this.lastClick || 0;

    if( event.timeStamp - this.lastClick > 200 ) {
        // do something
        alert('click');
    } else {
        // last click occured below 200ms, set out `lastClick` to the current timestamp
    }

    this.lastClick = event.timeStamp;
});
```

I am slightly sloppy here, storing the `lastClick` on the DOM elements object representation. You might want to put that variable in a higher scope of your app.

Comment: @jAndy, is lastClick a valid property ? :O

Comment: It won't work, because I don't know the exact amount of time.

Comment: @KsLdsad: well, yes its a valid property, we are creating it on our own there. In this example, its checking whether or not the last click on the specific element occured below 200ms. You can of course adapt that value to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is rogue way of doing it.

Have a global variable,

Inside the click event , increment it.

When enough clicks accumulated, remove the click event from the element using `$(this)` object

Answer (score 0):

I am modifying you code a bit,

```
var counter =0;
$("#something").click(function() {  
counter++;
//alert("Clicked : " + counter);
};
```

I hope this is the simplest way to know how many times it clicked.

if want to control clicks, just check with if

```
if(counter >= 1) {...}
```

I think this will do :)

Comment: It's not that simple unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Use .dblclick() (JQUERY) -- double click
Use .click() (JQUERY) - single click

If 1,2 clicks is pretty enought for your task - use them.

Good luck.

Comment: Not an answer. Worth as a comment